# how to refresh my DataGridVIew without stopping the code execution

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I have a table BOOK that contains (id, name, price... ) I want to edit the price of a book and i want the new price to be shown on a data grid view automatically while the code is running how can i manage to do it using threads, i m not having problems fetching data from data base , i want the DataGridView to be refreshed automatically once i change the price of a book in SQL server and i want this to happen without stopping the code and run it again or with a refresh button i want to accomplish this using threads.

Comment: Are there any events you can subscribe to when it changes? Or possibly could use a timer and check for updates on an set interval. If you post code I may be better able to suggest a solution

Comment: There are ways for the server to "notify" your code when the DB Data has changed using the SqlDependency Class. There is a somewhat simpler means using a DataAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution would be to use a timer (https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=netframework-4.8) that refreshes your datagridview.datasource.

Be aware that this will replace all rows. If you want the user not to see that you could call .SuspendLayout(), do the refresh and then call .ResumeLayout.

The better solution would:
- use a BindingList as the datasource of the DataGridView
- use a timer that gets only the updated objects from the database and replaces them in the BindingList
- due to the BindingList the DataGridView will automatically know what objects have changed and will only redraw those lines